# How to know which section is selected ? Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I’m working on a *dynamic* `tableView` with a lot of items, divided into *sections*, based on their selection. The *sections* are the client names, the items (i.e. the `rows` in each *section*) are the foods selected by the client. So far I'm having some issues about how to update it.
I used a table with 4 buttons (C1,C2,C3,C4).
 Then when a client is selected i append it in an empty array (client) that i use for the header section.
 
I've also created 4 empty *arrays* for each *section* (`myarray`,`c2array`,`c3array`,`c4array`) that I fill with the item selected by the client but there's a confusion in a part of my *code*.

In order to fill the `cell` for each `row` I wrote this:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Leschoix", for:indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.row]
        }

    if indexPath.section == 1  {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = c2array[indexPath.row]
    }

    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = c3array[indexPath.row]
    }

    if indexPath.section == 3 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = c4array[indexPath.row]
    }

        }
```

After running a quick simulation it I get this

---

1. C1: meal A meal B  (I select C1 and chooses 2 meals A and B)

---

2. C2: meal C meal D

Now when I try to add a meal E to C1 again (I select C1 button) I get:

---

2. C2: meal C meal D meal E instead of updating C1

So my *code* is saying if there's 1 *section* fill the *array* with the text, if there are 2 *section*, fill it with `c2array`, and so on..and in this case we have 2 *sections* so it won't update the 1st one. which means I can't update the first section. How can I say **If you're in the *section* i then update the appropriate array**?.  I'm looking for a way to say that whenever client i is selected then i'm in *section* j and fill/update the corresponding array accordingly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the flow is to select a button (C1/C2/C3/C4) and then you select any meal (A/B/C/D/E...) to be added.

Here's a solution.

> Maintain a variable in your class `selectedCustomerIndex: Int` and when button C1 is selected update `selectedCustomerIndex` to 0, for C2 set it as 1, for C3 set it as 2 and so on.

So now when you add any meal, add it to the appropriate array (myarray, c2array, c3array...) depending upon the value of `selectedCustomerIndex`

Something like this:

```
switch selectedCustomerIndex {
    case 0:
        //add to myarray
    case 1:
        //add to c2 array.
    .
    .
    .
    .
    default: //do nothing.
}
```

And then reload your tableview.

Personally I feel there are a lot of better and scalable approaches to structure the solution to what you're trying to build in your app, but this should serve well as a quick-fix. Hope it helps!.

Comment: thank you for your help. In fact the flow is to select C1 or C2 or C3 or C4 we don't care which one is the 1st. The flow is not 1 2 3 4. there is no order. what is your suggestions in terms of better approach? I was thinking about using struct and dictionnary but since i've already started it this way i'd rather go through it

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are working in tableview following snippet may help you

your button on tableview cell :

```
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.section
cell.btnselectedClient.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAddMeTap(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Detect which section button got tap and add element to your array according to your requirement

```
func buttonAddMeTap(sender:UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        print("first")
    case 1:
        print("Second")
    case 2:
        print("third")
    case 3:
        print("fourth")

    default: 
        print("default")
    }
}
```